# Laravel adding number row to query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am getting users and their points, I order them by points and paginate. Now I want to add a number row to result, so first placed user would have num. row 1, second 2 etc.

Currently I have this:

```
$scores=DB::table('scores')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'scores.user_id') 
                           ->join('sports', 'sports.id', '=', 'scores.sport_id')
                           ->join('leagues', 'leagues.id', '=', 'scores.league_id')
                           ->select('users.username','points','sports.sportName','leagues.leagueName')
                           ->orderBy($request->sort, $request->direction)->paginate(4);
return json_encode($scores);
```

EDIT: I am using vue-tables 2 so after API return table is created automatically and I can't print row number with foreach. Expected result would be:

```
Num.    Username    Points
1       test2       55
2       test5       42
3       test1       25
4       test4       5
```

JSON result:

```
{"data":[
    {"num":"1","username":"test2","points":22},
    {"num":"2","username":"test1","points":13},
    {"num":"3","username":"test4","points":12}
]
```

}

Comment: why can't you just add users.id to your select?

Comment: Is it important that the query adds the row number? Or can you use a `foreach()` loop?

Comment: @staskrak Because when I order by points then users get mixed up and ids are not ordered.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir This is in API and I need to return it in json, I could return array if that would help, but I cant print with foreach

Comment: What I meant: `$number = 1; foreach($scores as $score) { $score->number = $number++; }`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I am using vue tables 2 and after API return table gets created automatically

Comment: What should the JSON response look like?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Updated post

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: That works, but as I have pagination every page starts with 1.

Comment: Okey, it works. I can calculate numbers for other pages from page and limit. You can add your solution so I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `foreach()` loop:

```php
$num = ($scores->currentPage() - 1) * $scores->perPage() + 1;

foreach($scores as $score) {
    $score->num = $num++;
}
```